# make textfield required based on anther textfield in strtuts 2

Tags: validation, struts2

in struts 2 how can i use the actionName-validation.xml to make a text field required based on another texfield value

i think this is done using custom validator but how?
i don't want to use javascript to do this.

Comment: can you describe your question more clearly? like `textfield2 has to be greater than textfield1` etc..

Comment: yes exactly, this is what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```xml
<validator type="required" short-circuit="true">
  <param name="fieldName">textfield1</param>
  <message>You must enter a value for textfield1.</message>
</validator>

<validator type="required" short-circuit="true">
  <param name="fieldName">textfield2</param>
  <message>You must enter a value for textfield2.</message>
</validator>

<validator type="expression">
  <param name="expression">textfield1 gt textfield2</param>
  <message>textfield2 must be greater than textfield1.</message>
</validator>
```

[See the "Short-Circuiting Validator" docs.](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation.html#Validation-ShortCircuitingValidator)

Comment: thank you, but what if i need to do some calculations on textfield1 before compare it to textfield2, can i pass the value of both textfields to a custom validator and there do what i want?
if the answer is yes, how?